# Powershell operating system architecture vs NodeJs process.arch

Tags: node.js, powershell, architecture

I am using a NodeJs app which internally calls `process.arch` to get system architecture and then builds a path based on the result, eg. - `path/to/file/x64/file` (application is selenium-standalone NPM package).

Now I need to build the same path in PowerShell script so I also need to get system arcitecture. But doing that with f.ex. `(Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor).AddressWidth` returns result without `x` - just `64` so my path ends up `path/to/file/64/file` which is wrong. My current fix is to explicitly add `x`:

```
$arch = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor).AddressWidth
if ($arch -eq 32) { $arch = 'x32' } 
if ($arch -eq 64) { $arch = 'x64' }
```

Do you consider this as as safe thing to do? Or is there a way from powerShell to get it already with `x` assigned?

Comment: This is certainly not safe, as 1) it makes the assumption that only 1 `Win32_Process` instance exists, and 2) it only assesses the _platform_ architecture, rather than the _process_ architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`process.arch` describes the bitness (or *word width*, or *architecture* or whatever you wanna call it) of *the current process* - because it's entirely possible to run a 32-bit (or even 16-bit) process on a 64-bit operating system.

To figure out whether a running PowerShell process is 32- or 64-bit (regardless of OS architecture), use `[Environment]::Is64BitProcess`:

```
$arch = if([Environment]::Is64BitProcess) { 'x64' } else { 'x32' }
```

Comment: Nicely done. Those interested in the complementary question - Is the _OS_ 64-bit, irrespective of the bitness of the current process? - can use `[Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem`